# change the path to php.ini or change the magic_quotes_gpc

Tags: php

how can I change the path to ini if i am on a hosted server?

> suPHP_ConfigPath
>   /data/30/2/38/95/2690747/user/2955185/htdocs/public_html   
>       order allow,deny
>       deny from all

this methhod does not seem to work and puting

> suPHP_ConfigPath
>   /data/30/2/38/95/2690747/user/2955185/htdocs/public_html

causes error 500, I found the path using `__file__` code
and what am trying is to disable the `magic_quotes_gpc` for joomla.
I would really be greatful since I have been here for hours

Answer (score 1):

```
ini_set ("magic_quotes_gpc", false);
```

If this doesnt work, you should talk with your hoster and ask him if your request is possible. If you just signed up somehwere for some webspace, this will probably the problem.

Comment: Well, then you have to talk with your hoster because he probably blocked access to the php.ini